# 2dArray to Json string

Tags: c#, json, multidimensional-array

I need to convert a 2darray to a Json string.

2dArrray input(3x2)

```
1,A
2,B
2,C
```

need output

```
{"1":"A", "2":"B", "3":"C"}
```

Getting output

```
[["1","A"],["2","B"],["3","C"]]
```

Comment: Which language? java? python? r?

Comment: What have you tried so far... how is the 2D array constructed?

Answer (score 0):

For python use dict:

```
x = [["1","A"],["2","B"],["3","C"]]
dict(x)
```

Comment: Most questions have tags below them indicating a specific coding language is being used in the post. Wait until you know for sure (it's the responsibility of the person asking the question to make it clear) before posting a language-specific answer. As the tags appear now, a python question to a C# answer will be regarded as "not useful" and likely down voted.